# Search for a newline Character C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, string, newline

How do i search a string for a newline character? Both of the below seem to be returning -1....!

```
 theJ = line.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
```

OR

```
 theJ = line.IndexOf('\n');
```

The string it's searching is "yo\n"
the string i'm parsing contains this "printf("yo\n");" 
the string i see contained during the comparison is this: "\tprintf(\"yo\n\");"

Comment: no repro - show your real code

Comment: That looks like the correct statement.  Are you absolutely sure the string has a newline character?

Comment: FWIW, `Environment.NewLine` on most Windows machines is `\r\n` and not `\n`.

Comment: @BrokenGlass, just because i didn't copy paste my code does not mean it's not real code... everything that is going on is mentioned in the question...

Comment: @BlueMonster what you left out is the declaration of 'line'.  If we saw the code for how you were generating it we could tell you for sure if, say, there really isn't a newline in it because you escaped the escape character or something like that.

Comment: Change your code to line.IndexOf("\n"); and you will see that it gets it.  What is happening is that when your development environment displays the string, it displays \\ as \, so it looks like a newline character.

Comment: @David: You mean `.IndexOf("\\n")`. Yes, that's exactly what's happening

Comment: @David ...Thank you David and StripingWarrior.. for understanding the issue and for helping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"yo\n" // output as "yo" + newline
"yo\n".IndexOf('\n') // returns 2
"yo\\n" // output as "yo\n"
"yo\\n".IndexOf('\n') // returns -1
```

Are you sure you're searching `yo\n` and not `yo\\n`?

#### Edit

Based on your update, I can see that I guessed correctly. If your string says:

```
printf("yo\n");
```

... then this does not contain a newline character. If it did, it would look like this:

```
printf("yo
");
```

What it actually has is an *escaped* newline character, or in other words, a backslash character followed by an 'n'. That's why the string you're seeing when you debug is `"\tprintf(\"yo\\n\");"`. If you want to find this character combination, you can use:

```
line.IndexOf("\\n")
```

For example:

```
"\tprintf(\"yo\\n\");" // output as "  printf("yo\n");"
"\tprintf(\"yo\\n\");".IndexOf("\\n") // returns 11
```

Comment: Thanks, the last bit you wrote is exactly what i was running into... thanks for your input..

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your line does not contain a newline.

If you are using [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) or [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) on newline, then each line in the returned array will not contain the newline. If you are using `StreamReader` or one of the classes inheriting from it, the [`ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) method will return the string *without* the newline.

```
string lotsOfLines = @"one
two
three";

string[] lines = lotsOfLines.Split('\n');

foreach(string line in lines)
{
  Console.WriteLine(line.IndexOf('\n'); // prints -1 three times
}
```

Comment: @BlueMonster - No, it doesn't. Or, if it does, it is not `\n`. How do you know it contains a newline? How are you getting the string - where from? Can you post that code?

Comment: @BlueMonster - You are seeing a single `\` because the debugger visualizer will display that for `\\`. So you have an escaped backslash followed by an `n`, not a newline character. I ask again - how are you getting the string?

Answer (score 2):

That should work although in **Windows** you'll have to search for '**\r\n**'.

-1 simply means that no enter was found.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are trying to do. Both may no be identical on some platforms.

`Environment.NewLine` returns:

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string
>   containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Also:

- If you want to search for the `\n` char (new line on Unix), use `\n`
- If you want to search for the `\r\n` chars (new line on Windows), use `\r\n`
- If your search depend on the current platform, use `Environment.NewLine`

If it returns -1 in both cases you mentioned, then you don't have a new line in your string.

Answer (score 1):

When I was in college and I did a WebForms aplication to order referencies.

And the line break/carriage return it was what I used to break a referense.

```
        //Text from TextBox
        var text = textBox1.Text;

        //Create an array with the text between the carriage returns
        var references = text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        //Simple OrderBy(Alphabetical)
        var ordered = references.ToList<string>().OrderBy(ff => ff);

        //Return the entry text ordered alphabetical em with a carriage return between every result
        var valueToReturn = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, ordered);
        textBox1.Text = valueToReturn;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Environment.NewLine is not the same as \n.  It is a CRLF (\r\n).  However, I did try with the \n using IndexOf and my test did find the value.  Are you sure what you're searching for is a \n rather than a \r?  View your text in hexadecimal format and see what the hex value is.